# Fatal error: Call to a member function diff() on a non-object

Tags: entities

I have an entityform that has a computed field.
In computed field,
I have to compute two time fields.

When I tried using this code that declares value for the two time field, it works fine

```
$timefrom = '06:00PM';
$timeto = '8:30PM';
$from = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:iA', $timefrom );
$to = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:iA', $timeto );

$ot_hour =  $to->diff($from);
$ot_minute =  $to->diff($from);
$hour = $ot_hour->format('%h');
$minute = $ot_minute->format('%i');
$hourtominute = $hour*60;
$total = ($hourtominute+$minute)/60;
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $total;
```

But when I used the variables from the entityform,

```
$timefrom_value = array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_time_from'));
$timeto_value =array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_time_to'));

$timefrom = $timefrom_value['value'];
$timeto = $timeto_value['value'];
$from1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:iA', $timefrom );
$to1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:iA', $timeto );


$ot_hour =  $to1->diff($from1);
$ot_minute =  $to1->diff($from1);
$hour = $ot_hour->format('%h');
$minute = $ot_minute->format('%i');
$hourtominute = $hour*60;
$total = ($hourtominute+$minute)/60;
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $total;
```

It show error "Fatal error: Call to a member function diff() on a non-object"

Why is this happening?
I need some help to solve this. thanks a lot!

Comment: Please don't edit your question in a way that invalidates the given answers. If you remove that code, the answer doesn't make sense anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're getting confused with your `$to` and `$to1` objects. There is **typo** in your code. Try this on your later code:

```
$ot_hour =  $to1->diff($from);
$ot_minute =  $to1->diff($from);
$hour = $ot_hour->format('%h');
$minute = $ot_minute->format('%i');
$hourtominute = $hour*60;
$total = ($hourtominute+$minute)/60;
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $total;
```